# Array evaluating to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Below I created a class method in a model called Movie that should return an array:

```
def self.all_ratings
  Array['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']
end
```

And in my movies controller I access it using the following instance variable:

```
@all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
```

However when it comes time to use it in my index view I receive the following errors:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

I believe I am creating the array properly but I could be wrong. Any suggestions why these errors occur?

Below is the view where @all_ratings is used:

```
%h1 All Movies

= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]"
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

And here is how I implemented @all_ratings into the controller

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
```

Comment: Post your view code, your array creation is functional.

Comment: You'll likely need to supply more information; while `all_ratings` is redundant, it's correct.

Comment: Just updated it with the view code

Comment: Wild guess: I think your `@all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings` is not getting executed. Can you check the location of that statement in the logic.

Comment: @Anil I updated the post to show how I implemented it in the controller. I simply added it in at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code to initialize an instance variable needs to be in an instance method.

(Otherwise the scope is the class, not an instance.)

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index # Or wherever
    @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
  end
end
```

If you need that value in several methods, you could use, say, a `before_filter`.

Ruby is different from languages like, say, Java. In Java, instance variables are defined outside instance methods, and are available in every instance method, with whatever value they were initialized with.

In Ruby, there are two (major) ways to handle instance variables: use a method like `attr_accessor` to create accessor methods, or initialize them inside an instance method, as shown above.

Once an instance variable has initialized, its value is usable from any other instance method. For example, in your comments you mention initializing it in a `ratings` method. Unless `ratings` is explicitly called, `@all_ratings` will *not* be initialized. In other words, if you make a `GET` request to `index`, the `ratings` method will *not* be called, and `@all_ratings` will still be `nil`.

If you explicitly *call* `ratings` from `index`, then `@all_ratings` will be initialized (by the `ratings` method). Once it's initialized in *any* instance method, that instance of the object (the controller in this case) has an initialized `@all_ratings` instance variable:

```
def index
  ratings
end
```

Now the value of `@all_ratings` is available in index's template.

*Without* putting the instance variable initialization in an instance method what you're actually doing is creating an instance variable in the *class* `Foo`, which is something very different:

```
[1] pry(main)> class Foo
[1] pry(main)*   @wat = self.class
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> Class
[2] pry(main)> f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fbfba8efba8>
[5] pry(main)> f.instance_variables
=> []
[6] pry(main)> Foo.instance_variables
=> [:@wat]
[7] pry(main)> Foo.instance_eval "@wat"
=> Class
```

Comment: It works properly when I added it the index method! However, when I create a method of its own, say def ratings; @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings; end; it fails. I'm curious what the science is behind this?

Comment: @Dylan The method needs to actually be executed in order for anything in it to be... executed. If you *called* `ratings` from the `index` method, the effect would be the same--the instance variable would be initialized. It won't be called by magic unless you use a filter, as I mentioned (and as Anil gives an example of), or you call it explicitly.

Comment: I understand your point about having to have an instance method to execute; as I mentioned I created an instance method called ratings to put the instance variable in. This caused an error on the webpage, but when I put the instance variable in the index method the code executed properly. I was curious why it worked in the instance method index but not ratings. Does the index instance method map to index view whereas the instance method ratings does not?

Comment: @Dylan Just having an instance method is not sufficient, the method must be *called*. The index method is called when you make a request to the index url, so the index method is executed, and the instanced variable is initialized. If the instance variable initialization takes place in a *different* method, "ratings" in your example, that method will not be called when the "index" method is called-unless you explicitly call "ratings" from your index method, as I stated.

Comment: your last comment really connected the dots for me - thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Dylan No problem, glad it helped. It's always obvious once it's obvious ;) Before then it can seem pretty opaque sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Please move `@all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings` inside the index action of the controller. If it is common to all actions, then put it in a before filter as follows:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :load_ratings

def index
..
end

<other public methods>

private

def load_ratings
  @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
end
```

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for the sentiment. The scores are not important. The fun is in solving a problem, helping, and most importantly, learning.